# Ajax Post Error - can you see the code error?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to get a simple Ajax post working.  When I post the headers and data to the URL using Fiddler, it returns Ok.  However from my ajax code it goes to the error: function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#lblAjaxStatus').html('ready');

        $('#btnAjaxLogin').click(function () {
            $.ajax(
           {
               url: "https://www.testurl.com/api/login",
               type: "POST",
               contentType: "application/json",
               headers: {
                   "From":"CC",
                   "To":"CCM",
                   "Language":"0",
                   "Offset":"-8"
               },
               data: { "loginId": "email@gmail.com", "password": "Password1", "vehicleType": "E", "deviceId": "ABCDEF", "clientId": "123456", "appVersion": "", "osType": "", "osVersion": "" },
               success: function (data) {
                   // results
                   $('#lblAjaxStatus').html('here ');
                },
               error: function (error) {
                   $('#lblAjaxStatus').html('error ' + error.getResponseHeader + '\n' + error.responseText );
                 }
           });
        })
```

I've tried to set data using JSON.stringify( etc ), tested from various desktops and even changed the URL to someplace else... Results always jumps to error function and displays 
function(a){var b;if(k){if(!h){h={};while(b=Eb.exec(g))h[b[1].toLowerCase()]=b[2]}b=h[a.toLowerCase()]}return null==b?null:b} undefined

I have no clue what is wrong with my structure or syntax?  Anyone see the 'error' in my ways??? thanks.

Comment: Have you tried removing the contentType option or changing it to 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' ?

Comment: If you're intent is to post a JSON payload, you should definitely be using `JSON.stringify` on the `data`. Also, `getResponseHeader` is a function so it should be `error.getResponseHeader()`. I suggest you change your error handler to `error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { $('#lblAjaxStatus').html('error ' + textStatus + '\n' + errorThrown ) }`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your JavaScript script code with this one

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#lblAjaxStatus').html('ready');

        $('#btnAjaxLogin').click(function () {

            $.ajax({
               url: "your-ajax-file.php",
               type: "POST",
               contentType: "application/json",
               headers: {
                   "From":"CC",
                   "To":"CCM",
                   "Language":"0",
                   "Offset":"-8"
               },
               data: { loginId: "email@gmail.com", password: "Password1", vehicleType: "E", deviceId: "ABCDEF", clientId: "123456", appVersion: "", osType: "", osVersion: "" },
               success: function (data) {
                   // results
                   $('#lblAjaxStatus').html(data);
                },
               error: function (error) {
                   $('#lblAjaxStatus').html('error ' + error.getResponseHeader + '\n' + error.responseText );
                 }
           });
        });
    });

</script>
```

your-ajax-file.php

```
<?php
    echo "Put The HTML Data here";
?>
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add double quotes when you pass the parameter. Remove all double quotes in parameters.

```
 data: $("#form").serialize() // #form is id of your form
```

you can get all variables values using `input` name

Comment: It appears OP wants to post a JSON payload. This will format the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`